# How to put multiple variables in groovy switch statement?

Tags: groovy

How to put multiple variables in groovy switch statement? eg. The if any variable is false, it will print "false" orelse print "true". The following script doesn't work

```
a=true
b=true
c=true
switch(true)
{
 case(a==true && b==true && c==true)
   println("true")
   break
 case(a==false || b==false || c==false)
   println("false")
   break   
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this work for you? `if (a && b && c) println "all true" else println "not all true"`

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement is for testing a *single* value against multiple conditions.

While the `switch` statement is [versatile](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html), when testing multiple variables, a plain old `if/else` is more appropriate:

```
if( a && b && c ) { println 'true' }
else              { println 'false' }
```

Alternatively you may use the `in` ([membership](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_membership_operator)) operator. It tests if the LHS operand (value) is contained in the RHS operand (collection).

```
if( false in [a,b,c] ) { println 'false' }
else                   { println 'true' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like the following, create a function that combines the three variables and switch on that.  But I would *not* recommend it; the combination function is an unnecessary new element that could easily be buggy. You're better off using a series of if/else statements.

```
a = true
b = true
c = true

switch(a.toString() + b.toString() + c.toString())
{
   case "truetruetrue":
     println("true")
     break
   case "falsefalsefalse":
     println("false")
     break   
   default:
     println("a different combination")
     break
}
```

[The above in Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxlTUEOwiAQvPOKSU8QEx9g4it8wUJBiQgGtvFg-nfBhrTVw-7OzM7sEs7gPFmhOzAdiPLybG6SjpwunH28SoUD9J6aDVXiLQAYKhZDu9FrODUdeFYfhyi_y0Etos6W7mvOUSh2bX_RRd1m62xsrIEp8K-fMHrnbLaRYdJD-0jsU9x_nz-CtU-j)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groovy.lang.Tuple](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Tuple.html):

```
a = true
b = true
c = true
switch (new Tuple(a, b, c)) {
  case [new Tuple(true, true, true)]:
    println "All true!"
    break
  case [new Tuple(true, false, true)]:
    println "b is false"
    break
  default:
    println "Something else"
}
```

One caveat here: bizarrely, Tuple `extends java.util.AbstractList` thus is an iterable "collection", AbstractList. And if you pass *a collection* in `case` label — groovy will try to do an "in list" [element membership check](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_switch_case). Meaning `switch ("bar") { case ["foo", "bar", "buzz"]: ...}` — will trigger.

For this reason, you need to wrap the concrete tuples in case-labels into a singleton list:
`case [new Tuple(true, true, true)]` not `case new Tuple(true, true, true)`.